# How to see content of another screen?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, xserver

I use laptop with xubuntu 20.04, and have another screen, connected through VGA. But that screen placed not on my deck, this display placed on another room, so I can't see content of screen. Is there was a method, so I can see whats going on that second screen? Can I start another xserver on that screen and look on that through some client? Because it's a little difficult to use second screen with xfce. I often miss my mouse pointer, and because screens have different resolutions - some widgets looks ugly.

Sorry for my English!

Comment: what's the output of `xrandr --listmonitors`?

Comment: `Monitors: 2
0: +*LVDS 1280/331x800/207+0+0  LVDS`
`1: +VGA-0 1920/509x1080/286+0+0  VGA-0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
xrandr --listactivemonitors\
|awk -- 'BEGIN { getline } { gsub(/\/[[:digit:]]+/,"",$3) ; print $3 }'\
|while read GEOMETRY
do
    x11vnc -clip $GEOMETRY &
done
```

or if you know geometry of your target monitor acquired by  `xrandr --listmonitors`

mine is as follows:

```
xrandr --listmonitors 

Monitors: 2
 0: +*LVDS1 1280/330x800/210+0+0  LVDS1
 1: +VIRTUAL1 1280/339x800/212+1280+0  VIRTUAL1
```

and I ran :

```
 x11vnc  -clip 1280x800+1280+0
```

in your case for second monitor:

```
 x11vnc -clip 1920/509x1080/286+0+0
```

then

```
 vncviewer -shared localhost
```

EDIT: There is a simple way with `xrandr`:

To switch to next monitor:

```
 xrandr --output VGA-0  --left-of LVDS
```

To switch back to default monitor:

```
 xrandr --output VGA-0 --right-of LVDS
```

Check out:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/530126/x11vnc-only-show-one-display-with-dual-monitor-guest

https://www.tightvnc.com/vncviewer.1.php

https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/x11vnc

Comment: Thanks a lot, that works! But I cant see my cursor on vncviewer. I try to start x11vnc with some options, like -overlay but thats doesn't help. Is there a way to show cursor too?

Comment: @КрошкаРу It shows pointer. In two monitor setup mouse exceeds boundaries. I think it stays in the first monitor. Try moving mouse far right or left. It should be visible. Or try `vncviewer -clip xinerama1`. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/357959/vnc-server-as-a-virtual-x11-monitor-to-expand-screen-problem

Comment: I start x11vnc with `-multiptr` and it fix this. Thanks again.